Why are my only options "edit" and "decline" (when "edit" doesn't work) for a flag on a deleted comment?
It looks like a comment being deleted no longer clears any comment flags (at least for duplicate auto comments), but there are only two options remaining (edit/decline), one of which doesn't even work:

(This comment was deleted when the question was closed.)
Shouldn't the options be helpful/decline?

Is this mod tool of some sort?

@ShadowWizard Yeah, mods are the only ones who can handle comment flags. I just didn't feel like finding the right tag for it.

Might be worth mentioning whether you're in the flag dashboard or looking at the flag on the post. - or that it happens in both.

I assumed so, but 1) the screenshot does not match the question (no "edit" or "decline", or any options there), and 2) it looked like you might just tried to edit a deleted comment, which ordinary user can also do (well, try to do) if keeping two tabs open. Anyway, thanks for the explanation. :)

I think mods should be allowed to edit deleted comments, unless that's too much effort. It seems a silly limitation.

FWIW, the confusing way to fix it is to decline the flag. Which marks the flag as helpful... See this mod team post

What is rhe point of editing a deleted comment? Nobody can see it except mods, and they would need to preserve the comment in the form as it was deleted. If it was deleted wrongly, edit is pointless; if it was deleted rightly, it stays deleted, the user can write a better comment if they want it to stay up.

@Nij It's there for mods to see forever - if it contains disgusting things, why force a mod to see it every time they look at that post?

If it's that bad, delete the comment directly, and don't show deleted comments unless you need to. All you do with an edit is obfuscate what happened on the post.

@Nij To be clear, clicking on "edit" here was out of desperation/curiosity, not because I'm out there editing deleted comments regularly. (Since this was an auto comment, it didn't contain anything objectionable anyway.) In any case, there shouldn't be a button that can only cause an error.
